# import a function twice in Python, Flask

Tags: python, import

I would like to import a function twice in `views.py` of a flask project. I have a class defined in `models.py` and I want to use the function `get_item()` in that class as a class method

```
import get_functions
class Shopping_list():
   ...
   def get():
       return get_functions.get_item()
```

but I also want to use the function `get_item()` outside the class as an independent function so that my `views.py` has the following imports

```
import models
import get_functions
```

this does not seem to be allowed since I get an error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name models
```

I could define the function twice, but I would like to avoid that. Is there a way to use the functions in `get_functions()` twice?

I notice that this seems to be a flask specific issue.

Comment: The code you've posted shouldn't give you an error.  What error are you getting, and can you provide a [mcve] of your code?

Comment: Are you talking about Django? Because if you are, I would recommend you put the Django tag on.

Comment: @jwodder I think he meant he got an error by running `import get_functions` twice.

Comment: hi I am not using Django but flask

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but maybe you want this: `get_item=get_functions.get_item`?

Comment: I updated the question... I did not realize that this is a flask specific issue

Comment: Is `get_functions` a module or a class? Because if it's a module, I don't think you should do type `get_functions` in the question without the parenthesis.

Comment: It's not Flask specific

Comment: Yeah, why did you put the [import] tag there?

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name models` this is not related to your functions make sure you have this model `models`;

Comment: The error you posted has *nothing* to do with Flask or with your `get_functions` module or with the `get_item` function. It's about trying to import a module that, for some reason or another, the interpreter cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're importing a module twice, not a function

You have a triangular dependency, which is why there's an error. You can separate out the `get_item` function like so in the model module

```
from  get_functions import get_item

class Shopping_list():
   ...
   def get():
       return get_item()
```

And the other import will work as expected, but I think you can also do

```
import models
# use models.get_item() since it's imported
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Solution for your problem:

```
from get_functions import get_item
class Shopping_list():
   ...
   def get():
       return get_item()
```

Why does this work? It's because it imports `get_item` from `get_functions`, so you could import the module. However, if you try to attempt `from get_functions import get_item` again, it might not work.

#### Ways to import the same function name in the script:

```
from get_functions import get_item
import models
models.get_item # From a model
get_item #Turns native, Because now it's on a new script
```

#### If you want to rename it:

```
from get_functions import get_item as get_functionsfromget_item
get_functionsfromget_item #Turns native, Because now it's on a new script
```

Comment: Why are you using `>` before the imports? And what does `(` and `)` mean?

Comment: @BryanZeng '>' is just to indicate you can simulate those commands on terminal. `(` and `)` are followed by `#` represents a comment, more information not intended to be compiled or processed.

Comment: I would rather not use `(` and `)` and rather use only `#`.

Comment: The prompt in the Python interpreter typically looks like `>>>`, and parentheses are not required in comments. More importantly, this doesn't really explain what was wrong in the original code and why what you've shown is correct.

Comment: Oh, and I thought that the python shell has `>>>` before typing in commands.

Comment: @BryanZeng and @ mkrieger1 sorry for this. I already updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry for spamming comments, but I don't understand why you're renaming `get_functions.get_item.get_item` as `get_functionsfromget_item.

Comment: @mkrieger1 this is an import issue, I just want to help by showing different ways to import functions from diff models without overriding it.

Comment: @BryanZeng it's just another way to import and rename if needed, that's all.

Comment: Umm, I think that you should leave the renaming to him if it's not important.

Comment: If it's okay with you, I would like to [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162668/discussion-between-bryan-zeng-and-alvaro-joao).